# How to mark an entire section as relevant to a link in html5

Tags: html, seo

I have an index page, which consists of the content name, which is the url to the actual content.
And in a element under it a longer description. 
Is there a way to associate this longer description to the link (for SEO) or may be it is not needed, as search engines will know this due to the content itself?
html for example

```
<dl>
  <dt><a href="fdsfsdf">the title</a></dt>
  <dd> a longer description of this content..............</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using a definition list will associate the stuff in the `dt` to the `dd`, but what is more important for SEO purposes is that the content on the page linked to has some relevance to "the title" in the link.